# What databases and listing sites exist for anime, manga, etc?

Tags: resources

**What are the major online databases of anime, manga, light novels, visual novels, and other related media? What are the differences between them?**

To qualify as an answer, the source should list a large fraction of series in some particular medium, not just one or a few related series. The primary purpose of sites here should be indexing information about series. While it's acceptable to link to sites that do have some information related to e.g. fansubs, the *primary purpose* of all links in answers here should be *indexing*, not providing download links. Also, databases which are out-of-date should be removed.

Non-English sources are welcome so long as they qualify, but please specify what language in parentheses.

> <sub>***Note***: This is intended to be the canonical reference for
>   questions like this to avoid lots of new questions coming in with
>   slightly different specifications. Please check the sites here to see
>   if any fit what you want before asking a new question. The answer is
>   CW, so feel free to add to it.</sub>

Answer (score 64, accepted):

All lists are alphabetized, for lack of a better method. If you have a better suggestion just go for it. For the moment, due to the size of this answer, the only things included for each entry are whether they list characters, people, and music from the series. If you want to add this, please do so for everything from a category, not just a single entry.

## Anime

All anime:

- **[Anemy](https://anemy.fr)**

  - Includes characters, people, industry, music, and file information
- **[anica.jp](https://anica.jp/)**

  - Includes broadcast info
- **[AniDB](https://anidb.net/)**

  - Includes characters, people, industry, music, fansub groups, and file information
- **[Anikore](https://www.anikore.jp/)** (Japanese)
- **[AniList](https://anilist.co/)**

  - Includes characters, people, and industry
- **[AnimeCountdown](https://animecountdown.com/)**

  - Includes broadcast info
- **[Anime News Network Encyclopedia](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/)**

  - Includes people and industry
- **[Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/)**

  - Includes characters, people, and industry
- **[AniSearch](https://www.anisearch.com/)**

  - Includes characters, people, and industry
- **[GAMDB](https://gamdb.com/)**

  - Includes characters, creators, and companies
- **[Kitsu](https://kitsu.io/)** (formerly known as [Hummingbird](https://medium.com/heykitsu/hummingbird-is-dead-long-live-kitsu-bda6ccfbbcce))
- **[Kurozora](https://kurozora.app) (Multilingual)**

  - Includes characters, people, industry, music, and broadcast info
- **[MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/)**

  - Includes characters, people, industry, music, and broadcast info
- **[sakuhindb](https://sakuhindb.com/anime/search.asp)** (Japanese)
- **[SIMKL](https://simkl.com/)**

  - Includes people, industry, broadcast info

Current/Recent Anime Only:

- **[AniChart](https://anichart.net/)**
- **[AnemyChart](https://chart.anemy.fr)**

  - Also includes older charts
- **[LiveChart](https://www.livechart.me/)**
- **[MOON PHASE Anime List](http://m-p.sakura.ne.jp/)** (Japanese)

## Manga

- **[Anime News Network Encyclopedia](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/)**

  - Includes people, industry, and publication info
- **[Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/)**

  - Includes characters, people, and industry
- **[AniSearch](https://www.anisearch.com/)**

  - Includes characters, people, and industry
- **[GAMDB](https://gamdb.com/)**

  - Includes characters, creators, and publishers
- **[Kurozora](https://kurozora.app) (Multilingual)**

  - Includes characters, people, industry, and publication info
- **[Manga Updates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/)**

  - Includes people and industry
- **[MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/)**

  - Includes characters, people, and industry

## Light Novels

All of the sites above which list manga also include some light novels in their manga section.

- **[LNDB](https://lndb.info/)**

  - Includes people and industry

## Visual Novels & Eroge

- **[VNDB](https://vndb.org/)**

  - Includes characters, people, and industry

## Live Action*

<sub>*Please remember that live-action series are only on-topic here if they're related to some anime or manga.</sub>

- **[AniSearch](https://www.anisearch.com/movie/index/page-1?char=all&sort=voter&order=desc&view=4&titlex=1,2)**
- **[JDorama.com](https://www.jdorama.com/)**
- **[MyDramaList.com](https://mydramalist.com/)**

  - Includes people and industry

## Games*

<sub>*Please remember that games are only on-topic here if they're related to some anime or manga.</sub>

- **[GAMDB](https://gamdb.com/)**

  - Includes characters, platforms, creators, and companies
- **[Kurozora](https://kurozora.app) (Multilingual)**

  - Includes characters, people, industry, music, and publication info

## Other

- **[Anime Bath Scene Wiki](https://animebathscenewiki.com/)**

  - Site dedicated to archiving bathing scenes from anime, manga, and other related media
- **[Anime Characters Database](https://www.animecharactersdatabase.com/)**

  - Site dedicated to characters from anime, manga, and other related media
- **[IMFDB](https://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Category:Anime)**

  - Site dedicated to firearms from movies, TV, and anime
- **[VGMDB](https://vgmdb.net/)**

  - Music from anime and video games, including many visual novels and anime-style games

Comment: Recent suggested edit added "fansub groups" to one of the entries. I know that MAL also has info on that, and so must have some other sites, but is it appropriate to add that info on this site?

Comment: @user1306322 It's a bit questionable. Generally, people should not use this site for the purpose of pirating anime, but this isn't a direct link to any fansub group. However, it's not clear to me that the information is even useful in the first place. This post is *not* intended to be a list of all features of every site listed; such a list would be too long. I'm personally of the opinion that this sort of information is too specific to be worth including here. Other opinions are welcome though, and I could see this going either way.