# Where can I read the Inazuma Eleven manga online?

Tags: inazuma-eleven

So far, I have only found chapter 1 of the Inazuma Eleven manga online. Is there any site where I can read all of the chapters online and legally?

Comment: Refer to this : http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/what-databases-and-listing-sites-exist-for-anime-manga-etc . According to mangaupdates, only 3 chapters were translated.

Comment: just a suggestion. For a sports type, anime is always better than its manga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no official English-language localizations of the *Inazuma Eleven* manga in existence, in print or online.

You can easily verify this by:

- checking the Wikipedia page for [*Inazuma Eleven (manga)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inazuma_Eleven_%28manga%29), which does not list any English-language localizations.
- looking at the [AnimeNewsNetwork encyclopedia page for *Inazuma Eleven*](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=10235) and seeing that this page also does not list any English-language localizations.
- searching Amazon for "inazuma eleven manga" and seeing that you get no hits that are actually manga.