# What's this manga with a woman with body image issues?

Tags: in-the-clothes-called-fat

I was in a bookstore and was looking at a manga listed as a josei manga on the back cover before I had to go somewhere else, and am trying to remember the title. I only looked at the first chapter, but these are the details I remember:

- The protagonist is a woman who seems to have issues related to body image. In the beginning, it seems that she eats very little for her breakfast and hopes that it'll be enough for later, but in a later panel we see her eating a lot of food.
- Her coworkers comment on her fatness at some point in chapter 1.
- Her boyfriend's name is Saito. If I'm not mistaken, he's cheating on her with one of the protagonist's coworkers. She discovers this when she sees them on the street together, and later asks him if they can go out together to some place, which he says is boring. She wonders how he knows this detail when he supposedly never went to said place. The coworker apparently went to a Yokohama hotel with the boyfriend and had sex "three times" with him.
- We see an image of the protagonist on her knees in the nude to show her having sex (during a discussion of something tangentially related to that with her coworkers) with her boyfriend.

My preliminary searches didn't give anything useful, but I'll try again later.

Comment: Why is 3 times quoted?

Comment: @PeterRaeves: that was more or less the exact wording used (well more accurately, she said that they "did it three times" or something like that).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're probably looking for [*Shibou to Iu Na no Fuku o Kite*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=14196) ("In the Clothes Called Fat"). This manga has a protagonist who is overweight and can't manage to control her weight at the beginning. The scenes you describe of her coworkers and her boyfriend happen in this. Her boyfriend's name is also Saito, matching your description. In order to try to keep from breaking up with her boyfriend of 8 years, she develops an eating disorder, which leads to further complications. The main focus is her psychology and self-esteem issues, as well as the issues facing some of the other characters.

The manga was published in 1997, and spans 15 chapters total (collected in 1 volume). The English version was published very recently by Vertical.

Comment: For some reason, the link provided is shown as suspicious when using Chrome. Just adding [the MAL page](http://myanimelist.net/manga/13881/Shibou_to_Iu_Na_no_Fuku_wo_Kite) here for anyone who needs an alternate info link.

Comment: @キルア Not sure what the problem would be with Manga Updates. It's listed at http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/what-databases-and-listing-sites-exist-for-anime-manga-etc and shouldn't have any real problems. But the MAL link is certainly fine as well.

Comment: It looks like an HTTPS issue. It's probably temporary, but worth mentioning.

Comment: Yep, that's it. I forgot to add that the manga appeared to be in a single volume when I saw it (and some minor detail about the protagonist's name, which actually gave me the manga title after a quick search) but yeah. Thanks!