# Is there a site like MAL that i can filter animes by genres?

Tags: myanimelist

I decided to get my animes into one list and tried MAL however even though there are lots of ways to filter and sort animes like by airdate I couldn't see any way to filter them by genres. For example, let's say I just want to see romance animes in my "planed to watch" list I can't do that in MAL without manually writing tags for them. So is there a site that allows me to do that?

Comment: Looks like [MAL has anime search, including genres](https://myanimelist.net/anime.php), or did I miss something? Otherwise, you could try some sites listed on [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4697/2516)

Comment: Oh, no no I'm not looking for finding animes I'm trying to filter them in **my list**. MAL can't do that from what I understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**AniList**](https://anilist.co/) can filter entries in your personal anime list by any of the following criteria:

- Status (All, Watching, Completed, Dropped, Planning)
- Format (TV, TV Short, Movie, Special, OVA, ONA, Music)
- Genres (Action, Adventure, Comedy, Drama, etc.)
- Country (Japan, South Korea, China, etc.)
- Year (I'm assuming this means the year the anime first started airing, since *Naruto* only shows up if I set it to 2002)

Here's an example screenshot from my own list (I highlighted the genre filter with a red square):

[image: A screenshot of an AniList animelist filtered by the "comedy" and "slice of life" genres]

Note: I'm only personally familiar with AniList and MAL. The [other anime tracking sites out there](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/what-databases-and-listing-sites-exist-for-anime-manga-etc) (e.g. Anime-Planet, Kitsu, AniDB, etc.) might have comparable functionality as well, but I'm not familiar enough with those sites to know for sure.

I actually still use MAL as my main anime tracker, and only made an AniList account because the anime list importer on AMQ wasn't working for MAL (probably related to MAL's API shenanigans that happened after GDPR came out). Fortunately, AniList can import anime and manga lists from MAL. There's an place to do this in the "Settings" section in your profile on AniList.

Comment: As an extra info, Anime-Planet seems to do the job well too