# What tools are available for keeping track of manga you’re reading?

Tags: resources

I read a lot of mangas/manhwas/manhuas (more than 150). It is really a bother to keep track of every releases: my Discord is about to explode from too many servers and I have tons of bookmarks to keep tracker of new releases on different sites. I've also used MyAnimeList, but it doesn't really help with tracking when actual new chapters come out.

Does someone know a way (app, site, or whatever) to keep track of every new release of manga?

Comment: MyAnimeList is probably the biggest go-to out there, given its proliferation and the fact that it's pretty much a household name for anime and manga fans.  Other ways to do this would depend on *where* you're reading your manga; if you have paid subscriptions to various services, I would imagine that they have a way for you to access the history of what you've read.  Indirectly, I'm asking, "What do you normally use to read manga, or do you buy the physical copies?"

Comment: Mal is always the platform to use because if all necessary features and the simplest user design/experience. there's another one called anilist which has a respectable user base and the cool thing is they opened their API for anyone who wants to build a clone of the site or a mobile app. in my case i keep track of my lists in both (manually) because they kinda complete eachother.

Comment: See this meta post: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/what-databases-and-listing-sites-exist-for-anime-manga-etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a web app specifically for this - It's called Kenmei. It lets you not just keep a list of what you are reading, but it's specifically built to keep track of chapter releases on different sites, both official an unofficial.

You can find it here → [Kenmei | Cross-site Manga Tracker](https://www.kenmei.co/)

I'd say closest comparison to this site would be [MangaUpdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/), but Kenmei is a lot more modern and has a lot of features that MangaUpdates doesn't have (like Smart Suggestions).

But it's still in alpha, so it's not as comprehensive in terms of data, so I'd go with @Makoto recommendation as well - use [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/) or [Kitsu](https://kitsu.io/) as a backup and place to find out more information, like synopsis and so on. But when it comes to just keeping up with latest releases of new chapters, I don't think there is anything better than Kenmei out there (at least on the web, there are mobile apps like Tachiyomi that does similar stuff

Here how it looks:

[image: Preview]

**Disclosure**: I am the developer for this app. After reading manga for almost 2 decades, I still felt like there was no easy and modern to use app for all the series I read. Which is why I decided to build Kenmei

Comment: Whatever, it is the kind of tool I was looking for. Better than MAL as it keeps tracks of wide sources, but I will not take the premium package, I want to be sure this is a long term product. Thanks for the share  Maxim.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this extension for your browser(works with safari too) [MAL Sync](https://malsync.moe) works with MAL, Anilist and Kitsu. It sends notification for any new release manga or anime in your list. if you're in android then you can use [TachiyomiJ2K](https://github.com/Jays2Kings/tachiyomiJ2K) for the same feature and more(this one is only for manga though)