# What are the most popular anime in the world based on viewership?

Tags: anime-history

Most lists that I've seen either aren't measuring based on viewership, are not backed by credible sources or even approximations, or are referring to something like MAL, which has obvious flaws.

Is there any **objective data** on which anime are the most popular based on worldwide viewership?

Comment: You can check other databases: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/what-databases-and-listing-sites-exist-for-anime-manga-etc

Comment: How is popularity being defined? Especially regarding worldwide viewership. Are we looking at how many people have seen at least 1 episode of a show? Valuation of the IP (including Blu-Ray, merch, tie-in work sales)? Cumulative minutes watched? (This is tricky because official numbers like TV viewership, official streaming site views and Blu-Ray sales exist but its impossible to get numbers relating to illegal streaming/fan subs which is rather prevalent).

Comment: There is no comprehensive data. But you'd likely get anime everyone knows already, anyway. Like Meitantei Conan or Dragon Ball. It's not a very useful metric, since there are few anime released in enough countries to even stand a fighting chance.